# React-Native Populate image with URL that has been converted from a blob

Tags: fetch-api, react-native

I am trying to populate an image with a URl

```
<Image source={{uri: this.state.imageURL}} style={styles.thumb} />
```

I request the image from the server, using the fetch API, and it returns a blob.

I then convert the BLOB into a URL using the following line:

```
var imageURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(attachmentBLOB);
```

When I console.log() the imageURL it prints:

```
blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8081/4ce24d92-0b7e-4350-9a18-83b74bed6f87
```

I am getting no errors or warning. The image is just not displaying

I am using the android emulator.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **Solution**

React-Native does not support blobs [ref: [Git/React-Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/854)]. In order to get this working I had to download [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) which returns a base64 string.

**Function that returns base64 string:**

```
var RNFetchBlob = require('react-native-fetch-blob').default;

getImageAttachment: function(uri_attachment, mimetype_attachment) {

  return new Promise((RESOLVE, REJECT) => {

    // Fetch attachment
    RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', config.apiRoot+'/app/'+uri_attachment)
      .then((response) => {

        let base64Str = response.data;
        var imageBase64 = 'data:'+mimetype_attachment+';base64,'+base64Str;
        // Return base64 image
        RESOLVE(imageBase64)
     })

   }).catch((error) => {
   // error handling
   console.log("Error: ", error)
 });
},
```

**Populate Image with base64**
I then populate the image withe the returned base64Image with:

```
<Image source={{uri: imageBase64}} style={styles.image} />
```

Comment: How can I display the base64 image. I have used RNFetchblob and it get encoded the image. But In my screen it not get displayed.                                                                          
        // binary field data encoded in BASE64
        { name : 'pet-avatar', filename : 'pet-avatar.jpg', data : RNFetchBlob.base64.encode(image_data) },