# Downloading multiple images react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

Currently, I have an array of images like this:

```
var images = [
    "https://www.example.com/1.png",
    "https://www.example.com/2.png",
    "https://www.example.com/2.png"
];
```

So what is the best approach to handle the downloading process and also when all images download completed I need an event for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fetch`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html)
 which is a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
total = images.length
loaded = 0
progress = 0
progress = () => {
    loaded += 1
    progress = loaded / total
}

Promise.all(images.map(i => fetch(i).then(progress)))
    .then(onComplete)
    .catch(onError)
```

For downloading blob data refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38804349/3344612).