# React native image uri request with cookie

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

Im using a session based authentication system for my app, my API calls works perfectly fine, however, when requesting an Image using this:

```
<Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png'}}
       style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />
```

The request isnt authenticated

However authentication is required to retrieve the image. How would you go about this? There doesnt seem to be any documentation specifically on this

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370189/react-native-populate-image-with-url-that-has-been-converted-from-a-blob

Comment: im afraid thats not entirely relevant, im sending headers now but to no avail

Comment: i am trying to say  first fetch your network request as you want then pass the blob result to <Image source={{uri:imageBase64}}/>

Comment: if i am to fetch it manually like so then yes, i can wrap a component around it. its kinda bad that it doesnt do it on its own though since the domain is still the same but anywhoo. thanks a bunch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass [headers](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#network-requests-for-images) with Image source:

```
<Image source={{
    uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png', 
    headers: {
        Cookie: 'cookie data here',
    }
}}>
```

Get your cookie from your API response:

```
fetch('apicall').then(res => {
    cookieData = res.headers.map["set-cookie"];
})
```

Comment: Thank you, yes that's what i ended up with except for the part where im getting the cookie in the response im getting it using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cookies which is guaranteed to always give me the latest cookie.